# get shared/server url using CocoaHTTPServer

Tags: ios, video, localserver, cocoahttpserver

I am creating application that play video using chromecast device on TV (Apple TV or monitor that support HDMI port). Application is playing url like "https://serveraddress/video.mp4" but its not playing the video stored in app bundle(local video).

I have found that to make video play in remote machine (here it is TV) have to create local server on iphone.

I found this SDK [CocoaHTTPServer](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaHTTPServer) I have run the sample application but not getting how to take video URL that is stored in app bundle.

Can someone please help me in this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This work great for me.

https://github.com/swisspol/GCDWebServer

Initialize as given in sample code (give document directory as root).

Than to access local file copy that file in document folder and than access using http://localhost:8080/download?path=new.jpeg

Comment: http://localhost:8080/download?path=new.jpeg this is taking so much time to load on chromecast. is there any other URL for this?